# A vector $V$ is parallel $\iff$ $\nabla V=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, soft-question

A vector $V$ is parallel $\iff$ $\nabla V=0$

Where $\nabla V$ is the total covariant derivative of  $V$ and $V$ is said to be parallel if it is parallel along every curve.

How do we take the total covariant derivative of a vector field? If we write $V = V_i \frac{\partial}{\partial_i}$ then I know how to take take the regular covariant deriviative, but it's weird for me to take the total covariant derivative of just one vector field, I feel like when I take the total derivative of tensor fields it is like a generalized product rule. Can somebody show me the details explicitly please? Thanks!

Comment: I've replaced `\triangledown`$\triangledown$ with the more usual `\nabla`$\nabla$, feel free to revert if you don't like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the covariant derivative as an operator $\nabla : \Gamma( TM) \to \Gamma(T^*M) \otimes \Gamma(TM)$. That is, it takes a vector field and gives you a vector field tensor a one-form. The one-form describes the direction you are taking the covariant derivative in. Assuming $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection, we can write this in local coordinates as $$\nabla V = d(V^j) \otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} +V^j \Gamma^k_{ij} \;dx^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$
where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ are the Christoffel symbols. So for example, 
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^s}}V = \frac{\partial V^j}{\partial x^s} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^j} + V^j\Gamma^k_{sj} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$

Comment: "So for example:" and then you take a standard covariant derivative. Are you just illustrating the fact that $d$ is the exterior derivative and $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ are christoffel symbols? Oh I see, you are taking an element of the tensor product where $\partial_s$ is a one form.

Where does the $dx^i$ come from in the second summand of the first expression?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa  $\partial_s$ is still the $s$th coordinate vector field. The $dx^i$ term picks out the direction. So, if you feed $\partial_s$ to $\nabla V$, in the first term you get $$\frac{\partial V^j}{\partial x^i} dx^i(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^s})$$ and in the second term you get $V^j \Gamma^k_{ij} dx^i(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^s})$. As you can see, you get the expected thing.

Comment: @mysatellite Hi mysatellite, I think it can be simplified, since noticing that $\nabla A(...,X) = \nabla_{X}A(...)$ is tensorial in $X$ so if we can check in coordinate vector field $(\nabla A)(...,\partial_i)=\nabla_{\partial_i} A(...)= 0$  then we are done. Since $V$ is parallel,so in particular it's parallel along the coordinate curve which has $\dot \gamma = \partial_i$ therefore $\nabla_{\partial_i}A = 0$ for all $i$.So the equivalent holds.